# How to generate java files from multiple wsdl url

Tags: java, gradle, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I am trying to generate java classes from wsdl and I could do this with single schema but I am confused how to use multiple schema. I am using wsdl url. Here is what I have done so far:

```
task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "http://myhost:port/WebSServiceV3/WEB-INF/WSDL/CustomerSearchServiceV3.wsdl"
    //ext.schema = "http://myhost:port/WebSServiceV3/WEB-INF/WSDL/CustomerUpdateServiceV3.wsdl" ---> need to know how to add this

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema,
                    package: "com.mycompany.csi.wsdl") {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure how I can add multiple WSDL urls and generate java classes. Thanks in advance!